# Is a good pratice to have these columns on a database id_user_created and date_created?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

When someone inserts some information into a database, this table has two columns `id_user_created` (user that created that information) and `date_created` (date that was created). This kind information is a good practice to have in a table or is better to save in a logger table?

**EDIT**

Example: I have a table 'score' with this columns:

```
id_score, id_class, id_subject, id_teacher, id_student, score, 
id_type_score, id_category_score, id_status, id_user_created, date_created
```

Comment: What's the difference between a table and a log table?

Comment: the log table is a table for logger information, register when someone do something in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use a separate table.  That way, you can keep track of multiple changes to the record.  I also specify whether it was record creation or record modification, and depending on the circumstances, the old value and the new value of each field.

Comment: I will try the way that you said. I liked.